# How can I change Superset's table data source?

Tags: apache-superset

I'm super new to the Superset environment. I need to change the source of our table data. When I'm in "Edit Table" page (Sources -> Tables -> Edit Record) I'm unable to do that. Is there a way of doing this?

You can find the screenshot of Edit Table page from the link below. I want to change the part highlighted with red.

Screenshot:

[image: Link]

Comment: Seems like a limitation. You should raise it on Superset Github page, and for now only option I guess is to add new dataset/table and then change source of your charts.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of superset are you running?
Version 1.0 has this functionality, refer to screenshot below

[image]